# Youtube bell button API reference

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

Is there a way to manage the notifications ("bell button") from within the Youtube API?

I've went through the latest documentation and YouTube not-that-active GitHub repos.

Comment: I would love the answer from someone inside YouTube...

Comment: Does anyone know what `subscriptions.contentDetails.activityType` is? I thought it was the bell setting but I guess not. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YouTube does not provide the notification API.